# Keras -- how to operation "symbol variable "

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

if my code as follow:

```
main_input = Input(shape=(16), name='main_input')
act1= Dense(10, activation='tanh')(main_input )
```

now I have as symbol `act1`, the shape is `(batch_size,10)`

if i wanna matrix `act1` to add `0.5` each point, or if i wanna to get the data,only include `act1[:,0:5]`

i am confused. Because in MXnet, there are some operation on Symbol variables but in keras, it looks like all in layer operation. How could I operate on a variable ....

Hope guys can help me . Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want to use a so called [`Lambda`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) function. Here e.g. the first case looks like this:

```
act1_new = Lambda(lambda x: x + 0.5, output_shape=(10,))(act_1)
```

and second one:

```
act1_new = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:5], output_shape=(5,))(act1)
```

In this example a first dimension is skiped as it represents a batch dimension.

Comment: thx. If i have a symbol a, " a = Dense(1, activation='tanh')(act1) ",
but I want the output of layer act1 to multiply the output of layer a.
def mul_x(a,b):
    ans = K.dot(a,b)
    return ans
but it's wrong. I can't broadcast one dimension to 10 dim

Comment: hello i want to ask..... If in keras, I want to creat a symbol for sum...Like
in a floop:　a =a +b..  At first, a should be zero, and each time a updates and plus a new value b.
lambda can create a global variable or return two values. Thx

Comment: Try `multiplication = multiply([act1, a])`. Import `multiply` from `keras.layers.merge`